# XML Signature validations fails

Tags: java, xml, signature

Here is my code that I am trying to work on to validate xml signature. For one xml file which contains xml that is signed with certificate of signing algorithm `md2RSA` , it works perfectly fine. But another xml which contains xml that is signed with certificate of signing algorithm `SHA256withRSA`, it fails.

Here is my code that I am trying to use to verify signature validation:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XMLSignatureException, XMLSecurityException
    {
        File f = new File("F:\\workspace\\signeddocument2.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(f);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Element sigElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, Constants._TAG_SIGNATURE)
                .item(0);

        XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(sigElement, f.toURI().toURL().toString());
        boolean verified = false;

        verified = signature.checkSignatureValue(signature.getKeyInfo().getPublicKey());

        if (verified)
        {
            System.out.println("Signature verified successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Signature verification failed.");
        }

    }
```

And here is the successful xml file that works:

```
<DocumentToSign ID="signme">
    <SubElement>
    </SubElement>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#signme">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>pt/SfGyAXhfkEwmQUqlg5Dsczp8=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
baPXBiRO+S96Fb6J1zllCe2SsjmUgkEMnGOVNkTAFa/97Dv365uVrHzfnekoAVgCojWXdQIMVBqi
+uJKjK9JmEH738ob0vkrSJiZgLqjnCnPxM0yDwGRHXrnVVLuKhfdDkp9Pevo/e8+X5wIiPaXHb/C
r1/5ZFk3raFdD6b72X/MsMp4m2894UOTw0jo/FHIYpOHib4P21aK/kIFGROJEXU7sKv+GswOFbuH
7zcmXldNV7z/mrqd3XZROGy3jFpp0C2pu3PSYUS8BQCabQQfaS97nh20TL1pFVDSi3UvG3TYa21d
aQZncnzKZsbXPy+642KgeXF71H7rQrmkhQKi+g==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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==
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></DocumentToSign>
```

And here is the xml file that is fails with signature validation:

```
<DocumentToSign ID="signme">
    <SubElement>
    </SubElement>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
<ds:Reference URI="#signme">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="xsd" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<ds:DigestValue>iG7dOuXItysItp3EXjvWcXssDgtidn/dX9ZSlBc96+s=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
NiZcgh4DNGAkGPX3BKrBbkew7b8PitNArw4gRGU/7603pQRe+So31u3pSmuqLPerQ/gp6SqkSzmA
8pbldKYodf6cNHeO+rSTIS0dOJvqduhfYDDSLaXOGMeeiJG3en1mu4/ZajdYAtQd7YuwHNR4XgIA
O4DKltY4nHH/TKMe/8cr0boz+D8ttldX5CjcSCYqmmlG6sM/fbUgNT832Mwqp3N6dRr/OrKvl1Lt
JRioJ4+JOdw6mZkRvxl3ga5/CWGvCaBxNbuZKBFdrHf+SVrXpeg0/E1/E2Sd1L5bVWYR2M1q3eXr
RkutToCkHzRTQARS+90lx8pNaxiR8bcbfD4Oag==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
**Some Certificate Value**
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></DocumentToSign>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong in second case. This is the error message I get for second case:

```
org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference verify
WARNING: Verification failed for URI "#signme"
Signature verification failed.
```

Does anyone see anything I am missing?

Comment: I am looking into this method `org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference verify` which basically calculates the digest from algorithm and xml and tries to compare against digest value in xml. It seems to be failing and not understanding why it will fail.

Comment: did you finally get it fixed?

Comment: @JosemyAB - The issue is not fixed, but I found out the reason. So I build a security token and then use JAXB to unmarshall my token to build SOAP response. That messes up namespaces and cause this issue with signature validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JosemyAB - Thanks for your answer.

I figured out the issue why `signature` validation was failing. The `XML` I was signing had different namespaces compared to XML I was trying to validate the `signature` for. That `transformation` was causing `signature` failure. Once I figured out the transformation, `signature` validation worked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that a tag is missing in your xml.

I found some information here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-xmldsig-core2-20091022/

If you search for "signame" you will see that the specification needs a tag: `<C ID="signme" xmlns="&baz;"/>` There is the full specification:

```
<A xmlns:n1="&foo;">
     <B xmlns:n2="&bar;">
       <Signature xmlns="&dsig;">   ...
         <Reference URI="#signme"/> ...
       </Signature>
       <C ID="signme" xmlns="&baz;"/>
     </B>
   </A>
```

Your XML do not has this tag. Could be the reason.